# Why does it output error crash?

Tags: c++, console

I am writing a code to analyze a game, and I have a problem.
This code goes through every combination of 7 six-sided dices (from 1111111 to 6666666) and for every combination it sees if the combination makes some points or not. So I tried to check if it could put in the console every dice-combinations and the points associated just to check and it ran fine until 1223353 but at 1223354 it "crashed", as the image shows.[Here we can see the console running my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPn1u.png).
So I don't understand why it just stops after ~10'000 iterations.

P.S.: I tried to run it in code blocks and it didn't work either...

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Post the code here as text, and the crash log.

Comment: You were given a crash log—did you look at? Did you run the code under a debugger? Did you do anything to help solve your own problem? Apparently not. And now you want us to solve it without even being able to see the code! We're not magicians. Crystal ball says it stops after 10,000 iterations because you overflow the stack. (How appropriate.)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l1kz2a974lwcpay/Stack%20overflow%20Question.rtf?dl=0

I couldn't add the whole code, which was too long so here's a link to see it!

Comment: I am sorry I really am not very good in C++, So I really don't know how to file a bug or run under a debugger, I don't even know what it means...
Please understand me...

Comment: Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix 'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash log.
Program ended with exit code: -1

This is what I get at the end when my code stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, when the debugger gets to this line it crashes:

```
if (sptopt[k]==sptopt[j]){ // here k == 3 and sptopt.size() == 3
    sptopt.erase(sptopt.begin()+k); // this line crashes
    sdesopt.erase(sdesopt.begin()+k);
    soptch.erase(soptch.begin()+k);
}
```

I have looked at the state of the variables at the time of the crash and indeed:

k == 3 and 
sptopt.size() == 3

Basically you are looping and erasing from a vector (which is very very inefficient from a memory perspective), and not checking that value of k is not equal/higher than the size of your vectors.

This is the stack I got:

```
Thread 1Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x00007fff95687f49 in _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell ()
#1  0x000000010001b8ab in std::__1::enable_if<(is_same<std::__1::remove_const<int>::type, int>::value) && (is_trivially_copy_assignable<int>::value), int*>::type std::__1::__move<int, int>(int*, int*, int*) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:1904
#2  0x000000010001b856 in int* std::__1::move<int*, int*>(int*, int*, int*) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:1913
#3  0x000000010001b802 in std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::erase(std::__1::__wrap_iter<int const*>) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:1676
#4  0x000000010001b675 in main at /Users/**/Documents/iosapps/Chat App/newdaf/newdaf/main.cpp:604
```

*Every* time you are about to access a vector that changed in size in a loop, you must add checks such as:

```
if ( ( k < sptopt.size() ) && ( j < sptopt.size()) &&
     ( k < sdesopt.size() ) && ( j < sdesopt.size()) &&
     ( k < soptch.size() ) && ( j < soptch.size()) ...
```

Otherwise you access/erase an element that does not exist. In the case of deletion you get a runtime error. When accessing only, C++ may not be so kind as telling you that you are not where you thought you were (it did enter the function with k being an invalid index), and your program from then on behaves very strangely.

So you need to look at your functions and make sure your variables never go over the dimensions of the vectors you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that is not the problem... I suspected it to be the problem but just before this line I have two for that allows the k and the j only to run if they're smaller than the vector (only two for because the three vectors sptopt, sdesopt and soptch are always the same size). Even though, I tried again by putting the condition if just before the two for and it didn't change anything to my program. Thank you anyway for your help, I really appreciate that!

Comment: @Daniel I looked at your code.  The lines you pointed out do not do anything except output a message that the two vectors are not the same size.  Then the program continues on into the nested loops as if nothing is wrong, so I beg to differ that the answer given isn't the problem.  If you want proof, replace all your `[ ]` with `at()` to access the items in the vector.  Don't be surprised if you now get a `out_of_range` exception instead of just a crash.

Comment: @didiz -- It's ok to check for the size, but to show up front the bug, using `vector::at()` instead of checking the size will pinpoint to Daniel exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Daniel I actually ran the code and my debugger showed me that `k` is out of range. Paul, using `vector::at` is a great suggestion for debugging this, I will use it here from now on!

Comment: Thank you very much! In fact I just had to set a condition that j<k because after it erased the vector line the j still would go for a round, which was the problem! Thank you for your help! @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Thank you @didiz for your answer!